# Playback devices right click crashes the window

Tags: windows-7, audio

if i go to playback devices > Reproduction and try to right click in any of the devices or click on `properties` it freezes, then stop responding then crashes.
[image]

I don't know what to do. Is there a way to fix it without formatin the computer?
Already reinstalled audio drivers.

Also trying [AudioSwitcher](http://audioswit.ch/er) but it crashes on start up =\

Answer (score 0):

I had the same happening with me. I've removed my audio drivers (VIA) and installed Realtek drivers that can be found [here](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#High%20Definition%20Audio%20Codecs). Good luck!